# how to fetch api data dynamically on the basis of click using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react js how to fetch api data dynamically on the basis of click button.in my below code i want to fetch data on the basis of click using react js .how can we do that .

https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d my api is this.in my below code i make one table and  i want when i click on row 1st that is airplane and when i click first row then fetch airplane data using this api https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d .

how can we do that.

is there any help.its very thankful.

```
var TableComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // Data
    var dataColumns = this.props.data.columns;
    var dataRows = this.props.data.rows;

    var tableHeaders = (<thead>
          <tr>
            {dataColumns.map(function(column) {
              return <th>{column}</th>; })}
          </tr>
      </thead>);

 var tableBody = dataRows.map(function(row) {
      return (
        <tr>
          {dataColumns.map(function(column) {
            return <td>{row[column]}</td>; })}
        </tr>); });
    // Decorate with Bootstrap CSS
    return (<table className="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        {tableHeaders}
        {tableBody}
      </table>) }});
        

// Example Data
var tableData = {
 columns: ['Service_Name', 'Cost/Unit'],
  rows: [{
    'Service_Name': 'airplane',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
   
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'cat',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
  },{
    'Service_Name': 'fruits',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
  }, {
    'Service_Name': 'pool',
    'Cost/Unit': 50
  }]
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <TableComponent data = {tableData} />,
  document.getElementById('table-component'));
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM plz check my code here

Comment: anybody help me out?? how can we do fetch api dynamically

Comment: anyone help me out i m totally new in this

Comment: You want to fetch a document on clicking a table cell?

Comment: Add onClick event where you want, fetch your data and save it to React state. When the state is updated, UI will be re-rendered automatically.

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky thanks for reply, yes in this api https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d so many url data. so i want fetch data dynamicaly when i click on 1st row is airplane then airplane data fetch in api like that

Comment: @Virtuoz can u help me and show me something in my code https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM .how can we do.its very thankful.

Comment: i want to make when i click on service name airplane then fetch data dynamically in api and open this "url": "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" how can we do that using react

Comment: like that i want all row

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help:

```
const MyTable = ({data}) => {
  const fetchSomething = serviceName => fetch(`https://whatever?service_name=${serviceName}`).then(...);

  return (
    <Table>
      <tr>
        {data.columns.map(column => (<th key={column}>{column}</th>))}
      </tr>
      {data.rows.map((row, index) => (
        <tr key={index} onClick={fetchSomething(row['Service_Name'])}>
          <td>{row['Service_Name']}</td>
          <td>{row['Cost/Unit']}</td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </Table>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply can u show me something  in codepen or codesandbox because i m not able to do that https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM here is my code and api link is there https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d

Comment: its very thankful if u can help me i m stuck on that

Comment: Nice solution, Michael! Seems to be more elegant than mine :)

Comment: its should not work i m checking now can u help m to show

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need something like this. Steps for implementation:

1. Add a click listener on your row
2. Implement handleRowClick function similar to the below implementation. Save all that you need from the response to the React state.
3. Show the result somewhere in UI, or just console.log it.

Here is some code below that might help you

```
class TableComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  handleRowClick = async () => {
    // make an API call here, sth like
    const url = "https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    this.setState({
      ...response,
    });
  };

  render() {
    var dataColumns = this.props.data.columns;
    var dataRows = this.props.data.rows;

    var tableHeaders = (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {" "}
          {dataColumns.map(function (column) {
            return <th> {column} </th>;
          })}{" "}
        </tr>{" "}
      </thead>
    );

    var tableBody = dataRows.map((row) => {
      return (
        <tr onClick={this.handleRowClick}>
          {" "}
          {dataColumns.map(function (column) {
            return (
              <td>
                {" "}
                <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={row.url}>
                  {" "}
                  {row[column]}{" "}
                </a>
              </td>
            );
          })}{" "}
        </tr>
      );
    });

    // Decorate with Bootstrap CSS
    return (
      <table className="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
        {" "}
        {tableHeaders} {tableBody}{" "}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

// Example Data
var tableData = {
  columns: ["Service_Name", "Cost/Unit", "Unit", "Units Requested"],
  rows: [
    {
      Service_Name: "airplane",
      "Cost/Unit": 50,
      Unit: "1 Hour",
      "Units Requested": 12,
      url:
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blue.png",
    },
    {
      Service_Name: "cat",
      "Cost/Unit": 50,
      Unit: "1 Hour",
      "Units Requested": 12,
      url:
        "http://codeskulptor-assets.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/assets_clock_background.png",
    },
    {
      Service_Name: "fruits",
      "Cost/Unit": 50,
      Unit: "1 Hour",
      "Units Requested": 12,
      url:
        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/asteroid_blend.png",
    },
    {
      Service_Name: "pool",
      "Cost/Unit": 50,
      Unit: "1 Hour",
      "Units Requested": 12,
    },
  ],
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <TableComponent data={tableData} />,
  document.getElementById("table-component")
);
```

Comment: can u show me something in code editorbcz its not work which u have share with me.its very helpful for me

Comment: @praveenakumari just take the Virtuoz component 'as is' and pass the table data as props, it should work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM can u  show me its very thankful. here https://codepen.io/kupraveen/pen/poRYJOM  just now i check its not happen

Comment: https://mocki.io/v1/be3cb19b-bd49-4a82-b19b-44b859e19d5d this is api

Comment: You won't manage it to work from codepen, because there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the requested resource. Either run Chrome in disabled CORS mode or set the needed header on the server side.